# Wowza and Video.js not streaming

Tags: javascript, html, video.js, rtmp, wowza

Im trying to run an rtmp stream using Video.js receiving from wowza. However I have been unable to get anything to play. The source is bellow, I have gone through every article and post I can find and this seems like it should work. But i can't get it to.

p.s. I have loaded the rtmp url bellow into VLC player and it loads just fine, so it is definitely live and streaming to that address

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Live</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="video-js.css">
  <script src="video.js"></script>
  <script>
    videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf";
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 <center>
   <video id="livestream" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered"
     controls autoplay preload="auto" width="1280" height="720"
     data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
      <source src="rtmp://192.168.32.15:1935/live/myStream" type="rtmp/mp4">
   </video>
 </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you getting any errors in the developer console?

Comment: @VasilDininski Nope, Nothing at all in the console from load or when the play button is pushed

Comment: "I don't think any browser supports rtmp protocol".replace("I don't think any", "NO");

Comment: see [documetation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/Live_streaming_web_audio_and_video#RTSP_2.0) - specifically the important warning just before the "Using streaming protocols" section - *Important: Although the audio and video tags are protocol agnostic, **no browser currently supports anything other than HTTP without requiring plugins** although this looks set to change. Protocols other than HTTP may also be subject to blocking from firewalls or proxy servers.*

Comment: @JaromandaX What is the best method to live stream via Wowza in that case?

Comment: @KristenTidmuss - http protocol

Comment: or read wowza [forums](https://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?38896-Can-wowza-stream-to-HTML-5-player) and [information](https://www.wowza.com/blog/a-note-on-html5)

Comment: @KristenTidmuss Try the HLS link `http://192.168.32.15:1935/live/myStream/playlist.m3u8`
You have to make sure you have enabled HLS playback on your Wowza application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the CDN version of video.js and it worked correctly with an RTMP live stream from Wowza.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.8.8/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 -->
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
  poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="rtmp://192.168.1.20:1935/live/myStream" type='rtmp/mp4'>
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
      <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>
  </video>

  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.8.8/video.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

You can also install the HLS plugin for video.js and playback the HLS stream from your Wowza server.

```
 http://192.168.1.20:1935/live/myStream/playlist.m3u8
```

Comment: I used your code. Replaced RTMP url by my rtmp url but it is not working. It is showing No compatible source was found for this media. Do you have any ideas? Thanks!